# SQL query count issue - attempting to only see multiple results over 0

Tags: sql

Having issues with a SQL query. I am attempting to select the account number, amount, and created date in a database. For that set, I am attempting to see all amounts over $0, within the last 7 days, and only accounts with over 3 instances of charges over $0 within the last 7 days. I've tried a few different things, but the issue I am having is how to build in the over three instances criteria. Any ideas?

```
select
   account,
   count(account),
   amount,
   created
  from account_charges
  where account_charges.amount > 0 and date(account_charges.created) >= date_add('day', -7, date(data_load_time)) 
  group by
   account_charges.account having count(*) > 3,
   account_charges.amount,
   account_charges.created
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Your HAVING clause is a bit lost.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah If I remove the having clause it works fine. Just trying to figure out how to build the criteria to only show accounts that have had three unique charges > $0 within the last 7 days.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm pretty new to SQL so I'm not really sure how to answer that, to be honest.

Comment: @dobrien SQL is just a query language. There are a myriad of dialects of it, that vary depending on the specific product (database) you are using. For example, you could be using PostgreSQL, Oracle database, IBM DB2, Sybase, MySQL, H2, SQL Server, etc. Do you know which one are you using?

Comment: @TheImpaler Ah got it thank you. It is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a simple copy-past error. Does moving the `Having` statement to the end work out better?

```
select
   account,
   count(account),
   amount,
   created
  from account_charges
  where account_charges.amount > 0 and date(account_charges.created) >= date_add('day', -7, date(data_load_time)) 
  group by
   account_charges.account,
   account_charges.amount,
   account_charges.created
  having count(*) > 3
```

Here is a variation you may want to consider. The query above will only return accounts that have the same amount that is greater than zero more than three times. Perhaps you want to count *all* amounts above zero by account instead?

```
 select
   account,
   count(*),
   max(amount) as max_amount,
   min(created) as created
  from account_charges
  where account_charges.amount > 0 and date(account_charges.created) >= date_add('day', -7, date(data_load_time)) 
  group by
   account_charges.account
  having count(*) > 3
```